# MongoDB can not start after restart the system on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've installed mongoDB on ubuntu 14.04 according to the official installation guide: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I enter the terminal using "mongod" and everything is OK.

But when I shut down my ubuntu and restart it, command 'mongod' just cannot start, one error happens below:

```
2015-01-30T15:47:51.582-0800 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-01-30T15:47:51.582-0800 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-01-30T15:47:51.583-0800 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
```

After that, I tried to create the folder and chmod it using:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

but another error happened:

```
2015-01-30T16:01:43.855-0800 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-01-30T16:01:43.855-0800 [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-01-30T16:01:43.859-0800 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-01-30T16:01:43.859-0800 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-01-30T16:01:43.994-0800 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-01-30T16:01:43.994-0800 [initandlisten] ERROR: addr already in use
2015-01-30T16:01:43.994-0800 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-01-30T16:01:44.197-0800 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...
```

I also looked for /etc/mongod.conf,

```
# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

#port = 27017
```

where I found the default data storage folder is not /data/db

I've tried other ways like

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod restart
```

But they simply do not work.

May be there's another instance already run when the system starts, but how can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ERROR: addr already in use` indeed means that you have another instance already running.

Did you try to:

- type `mongo` in the terminal and see if it connects to the server?
- check the logs in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`? Do they tell you an instance is up?
- type `ps -edf | grep mongod` and see if any process is running? I suppose it's not a good practice but did you try to `kill` it if one shows up, and type `mongod` again?

Aynway, you may want to try two things:

- When you type `sudo service mongod stop` and before the `sudo service mongod restart`, try to type `mongod` in the terminal. As you normally stopped the running instance, you should be able to start your own
- You could try to start another instance. For that, you will have to specify at least the `port` (and chose a different one than the default one), and preferably the `dbpath` (make sure to chose a path to a directory that already exists). You can do that on the command line, for example:

> $ mongod --port 28000 --dbpath /path/to/your/db

Or you can create your own `mongodb.conf`, based on the default one, change the values for `port` and `dbpath`, and start `mongod` specifying the path to this config file:

> $ mongod -f /path/to/your/mongod.conf

Comment: Wow, I got it. I mistakenly type 'mongod' instead of 'mongo' to run the script shell. Anyway, thanks very much!